# XPath Query C# to pull out nodes dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am  having to write a XPath Query to pull out the answer for a question based on the question id. The question id is passed dynamically to the query. I cannot use LINQ as the solution is in NET 2.0.  Please find the XML file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Questionaire>
  <question id="1">
    <answer>1</answer>
    <correctAnswer>Text</correctAnswer>
  </question>
  <question id="2">
    <answer>2</answer>
    <correctAnswer>Text</correctAnswer>
  </question>
</Questionaire>
```

I'am a novice to XPath and find it hard to get my head around it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your XPath expression can be dynamically generated like this**:

```
myExpression = string.Format("/*/*[id='{0}']/answer", theId);
```

then, depending on the object representing the XML document you need to call one of the following methods: `Select()`,  `SelectNodes()`, `SelectSingleNode()`, `Evaluate()`.

**Read the MSDN documentation about** the appropriate methods of `XmlDocument`, `XPathDocument`, `XPathNavigator` and `XPathExpression`.

Comment: Many thanks for all the contributions. I did come closer to @Dimitre answer in the end but found his answer here and it works fine. Thanks again you guys rock!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class and the [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx) method to perform XPath queries. You may checkout the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx) for examples. In your case the XPath query will be something along the lines of `Questionaire/question[id='1']` where the id could be variable of course in order to fetch the corresponding node. Once you find the `<question>` node corresponding to your search criteria you could navigate to its child nodes.

Comment: @_Darine, The OP wants to select the answer, not the question.  This can be accomplished evaluating a single XPath expression. :)